# Error when working with thread and VTK

Tags: multithreading, graphics, c++-cli, vtk

I am using C ++ / Cli
and now I'm getting that by importing a dicom file in a separate thread. The problem is that the thread does not seem to accept the syntax, it accuses the vtk as a member unmanaged ..

below this code.

```
vtkDICOMImageReader* UCConfigurarEstudo::GetDicom()
{
    if (dicomReader == nullptr)
    {
        dicomReader = vtkDICOMImageReader::New();

        //Converter String^ para char*
        IntPtr ptrToNativeString = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(DadosRequisicao::local_arquivo_DICOM);
        char* nativeString = static_cast<char*>(ptrToNativeString.ToPointer());
        dicomReader->DebugOff();
        dicomReader->SetDirectoryName(nativeString);
        dicomReader->SetDataExtent(0, 63, 0, 63, 1, 93);
        dicomReader->SetDataSpacing(3.2, 3.2, 1.5);
        dicomReader->SetDataOrigin(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        dicomReader->SetDataScalarTypeToUnsignedShort();
        dicomReader->SetDataByteOrderToLittleEndian();

        Thread^ thread2 = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(*dicomReader, &vtkDICOMImageReader::UpdateWholeExtent));
        thread2->Name = "thread2";
        thread2->Start();
        //dicomReader->UpdateWholeExtent();


    }
    dicomReader->Update();
    return dicomReader;
}
```

errors:

Error 1 error C3364:

> 'System :: Threading :: ThreadStart': Invalid argument to delegate constructor; delegate destination must be a pointer to a member function D: \ projects \ XDicom \ XDicom \ UCConfigurarEstudo.cpp 545 1 XDicom

Error 2 error C2512:

> 'System :: Threading :: Thread :: Thread': no ​​appropriate default constructor available D: \ projects \ XDicom \ XDicom \ UCConfigurarEstudo.cpp 545 1 XDicom
>   3 IntelliSense: invalid initiator delegate - function is not a member of a managed class d: \ projects \ XDicom \ XDicom \ UCConfigurarEstudo.cpp 545 66 XDicom

help me!

Comment: You are getting yourself into a lot of trouble, beyond the correct compiler errors.  You are returning a pointer to an image object that isn't done loading yet.  And you have no idea when it is done.  Fall in the pit of success by using the BackgroundWorker class, you need its RunWorkerCompleted event.

Comment: Hans, the part of * dicomReader ended up by mistake in code it is not present, was just a excuse me test.

About BackgroundWorker, but still would not give to use it, so if I add somehow one addobservece in dicom update.